# Where is the SQLite database file stored in an Blackberry 10 app developed with Titanium?

Tags: titanium, appcelerator, blackberry-10

I'm trying to build an BlackBerry 20 app with Appcelerator Titanium where I'm using SQLite functionality with the Titanium Ti.Database object. Ti.Database creates and manages a SQLite database in the app. The database is created fine and contains values which I can get by a SQL query.

Running the app in the simulator I have access to /accounts/1000/appdata/ folder. I looked at every subfolder, but I didn't found any file where my SQLite data is stored.

So, where does a BlackBerry 10 store such a SQLite database file?

Comment: I don't know either, I also know support for BB with Titanium is minimal, and as far as I know Appcelerator will not pursue developing more for it. So I recommend not using Titanium for BB. (And I'm a big Titanium enthousiast)

Comment: Thanks, I'll ask Appcelerator about the future of BB10 support.